# How do I dynamically create subarrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Current output: `[set1, set2, set3]`

Desired output: `[[set1], [set2], [set3]`

Assuming I have variables `set1`, `set2`, `set3`, and an empty array:

`arr = [];`

I know I can push the variables into my array like so:

`array.push(set1, set2, set3);`

and if I do `console.log(arr)` the output will be:

`[set1, set2, set3]`

But I want to push each variable to its own subarray within the array, so that the output looks like:

`[[set1],[set2],[set3]]`

I am having a very difficult time figuring out the syntax for this. I've tried things like:

`array[pos].push(set1)`

but this results in a `TypeError (Cannot read properties of undefined)`.

I've tried `tempArray.splice(tempArray[pos], 0, set1);`

but that just results in a single array again.

What is the correct way to push values into a subarray?

Comment: perhaps `array.push([set1])`

Comment: `arr.push([ set1 ])` ?

Comment: Replace `array.push(set1, set2, set3);` with `array.push([set1], [set2], [set3]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array literal syntax:

```js
const set1 = 'set1', set2 = 'set2', set3 = 'set3';

const arr = [];

arr.push([set1], [set2], [set3]);

console.log(arr);
```

If your variables come in an array you could map them:

```js
const set1 = 'set1', set2 = 'set2', set3 = 'set3';

const arr = [];

const scalarArr = [set1, set2, set3];

arr.push(...scalarArr.map(item => [item]));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. How can I then refer to these subarrays later, if I want to put something else in them? For example, if a number from my array fulfills a certain rule for a set, I want to push it to the relevant subarray. But I don't know ahead of time how many sets or subarrays there will be, so I have to find some way to refer to them dynamically. This is where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: @MBWD no problem in using/accessing the subarrays with the arr variable

Answer (score -1):

Do it individually.

```
arr.push([set1]);
arr.push([set2]);
arr.push([set3]);
```

Comment: I downvoted because a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/76720964/16540390 isn't helpful.

Comment: Oh no! I didn't see that at the time of my answer. You know when writing an answer it doesn't show new answers that are being posted. : /